# How to find out the location of x,y,z from every corner of the building?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Is there a method from Autodesk Forge to find out the location of each point from the corner of the building like the picture I attached?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Forge Model Derivative & Viewer, the geometries have been translated to mesh (triangles). It does not contain the information of face/edge, which means it does not tell which is corner of the shape. you may have to calculate which is the furthest vertex. This is a blog about how to get vertex
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-mesh-triangles-data-hittest